# Returning Twilio Response Warning

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Getting the following API warning in Twilio:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ArrayOfanyType'.

Here's my code:

```
   public TwilioFluent.TwiML.TwilioResponse Post(TwilioTextMessageRequest request)
   {
            ....//Do some stuff

            var response = new TwilioFluent.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
            return response;
   }
```

I have tried every conceivable way to send back the response without error messages to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks